# Refrescar Activity o List (Lo que sea mejor) Android

Tags: android, android-listview

Buenas tengo el siguiente `activity` que me crea una lista con datos traídos por `php` y `mysql`.
Como puedo hacer para que esa listase actualice cada cierto tiempo o refrescar el activity sin tener que usar el boton algo asi como un meta refresh.
Muchas gracias.

```
public class PreAsignado extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView listado;
Button Volver;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pre_asignado);
    listado = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ObtDatos();
    Volver = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnVolver);
    Volver.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

       @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent btnAceptar = new Intent(PreAsignado.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(btnAceptar);
        }
    });
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
}
public void ObtDatos(){
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    String url = DIRECCION + "getDataPreAsignados.php";
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String email = sharedPreferences.getString(Config.EMAIL_SHARED_PREF,"No disponible");
    RequestParams parametros = new RequestParams();
    parametros.put("email", email);
    client.post(url, parametros, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            if (statusCode == 200){
                CargarLista(obtDatosJSON(new String(responseBody)));
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
        }
    });
}
public void CargarLista(final ArrayList<Pedido> datos){
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    for (int i=0;i<datos.size();i++)
    {
        adapter.add(datos.get(i).toString());
    }
    listado.setAdapter(adapter);
    listado.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),Detalle.class);
            intent.putExtra("id",datos.get(position).getId());
            intent.putExtra("barrio",datos.get(position).getBarrio());
            intent.putExtra("direccion",datos.get(position).getDireccion());
            intent.putExtra("pisoDepto",datos.get(position).getPisoDepto());
            intent.putExtra("cliente",datos.get(position).getCliente());
            intent.putExtra("telefono",datos.get(position).getTelefono());
            intent.putExtra("cadete",datos.get(position).getCadete());
            intent.putExtra("pagaCon",datos.get(position).getPagaCon());
            intent.putExtra("estado",datos.get(position).getEstado());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
    );
}
public ArrayList<Pedido> obtDatosJSON(String response){
    ArrayList<Pedido> listadoArray = new ArrayList<Pedido>();
    try{
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
        Pedido p;
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length();i++){
            p = new Pedido(
                    Integer.parseInt( jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id")),
                    jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("barrio"),
                    jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("direccion"),
                    jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("pisoDepto"),
                    jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("cliente"),
                    jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("telefono"),
                    jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("cadete"),
                    jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("pagaCon"),
                    jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("estado")
            );
            listadoArray.add(p);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return listadoArray;
}
}
```

---

Disculpen pero soy muy nuevo con esto, estoy buscando onResume como me comentan, lo uso y el codigo me da error y al arreglarlo queda asi:

```
public static final long PERIODO = 60000; // 60 segundos (60 * 1000 millisegundos)
private Handler handler;
private Runnable runnable;



protected void onResume(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onResume();
    handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void publish(LogRecord record) {

        }

        @Override
        public void flush() {

        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws SecurityException {

        }
    };
    runnable = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            handler.postDelayed(this, PERIODO);
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, PERIODO);
}
```

postDelayed me dice:

> Error:(74, 24) error: cannot find symbol method
>   postDelayed(,long)

Me guían por favor que buscar para comprender lo que me esta pasando y poder implementarlo sin errores? Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tienes tu método para obtener datos: `ObtDatos()` , el cual llama a su vez la carga el `Activity` con los datos actualizados `CargarLista()`, puedes usar un `handler` que mande llamar el primero.

Como ejemplo este proceso llamaría `ObtDatos()` cada 60000 millisegundos (1 minuto)

```
   final long EXECUTION_TIME = 60000; // 1 minuto

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            ObtDatos();

            handler.postDelayed(this, EXECUTION_TIME);
        }
    }, EXECUTION_TIME);
```

Comment: Agradezco tu respuesta pero la verdad no entiendo donde meter  ese codigo en lo que ya arme, no es de vago, estoy buscando, hace poco que empece con esto y voy muy lento, me dirias donde meterlo o que buscar para saber como implementar ese codigo e insertarlo en el mio? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Seria asi? No da errores pero no refresca el activity:    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        final Handler handler = new Handler();

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.postDelayed(this, EXECUTION_TIME);
            }
        }, EXECUTION_TIME);

    }

Answer (score 1):

No conozco el caso de uso, pero normalmente no es necesario refrescar peródicamente una lista con la que interactúa el usuario. Normalmente la actualización se hace porque ocurre un evento, como ser que el susuario vuelve a la pantalla donde está la lista.

Refrescar la lista desde Internet periódicamente, incurre en gastos de batería, y podría también consumirle parte del paquete de datos sin que el usuario lo sepa o lo necesite.

Si fuese suficiente para tu app refrescar cuando el usuario interactúa con la lista, sería sólo cuestión de hacer la bajada del `json` y el reemplazo del `set de datos` en el `adapter` de la lista dentro del método `onResume()` del `Activity`.

Si manejaras `Fragments` se puede hacer en `onResume()` o en `onActivityAcreate()` dependiendo de que otras dependencias puede tener el `Fragment` con la `Activity` que lo contiene.

Otra alternativa, que creo se sale del contexto de la pregunta, es que si la actualización depende de eventos que ocurren en el servidor, sería posible utilizar un framework de Push como pueden ser Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM), sólo o a en conjunto con OneSignal o Urbanairship. Estos productos te permiten recibir una "señal" desde tu server cuando la app debería actualizar algún dato.

**EDICIÓN 1**

Habiendo dicho lo anterior, si realmente crees que necesitas un refresh periódico mientras el usuario está en la Activity, lo podes implementar con un Handler que se active en `onResume()` y se desactive en `onPause()`.

```
public static final long PERIODO = 60000; // 60 segundos (60 * 1000 millisegundos)
private Handler handler;
private Runnable runnable;
```

En onResume():

```
handler = new Handler();
runnable = new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
         <Bajar los datos y refrescar la lista>
         handler.postDelayed(this, PERIODO);
    }
}
handler.postDelayed(runnable, PERIODO);
```

En onPause():

```
handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
```

Comment: En el panel web cargan info, esa info se ve en este activity, lo que ando necesitando es un refresh, timer o algo que me actualice la lista cada cierto tiempo asi me sale la info que cargan en el panel en la app sin salir, algo mas o menos asi